# The operation couldn't be completed. cpio read error: Undefined error: 0

Tags: xcode, installation

**I am Getting Above error while installing Xcode 8.**[image]

This time I have got Xcode_8.xip Xcode file from apple.
My current OS version is 10.11.4 (15E65).

Even I have successfully installed xcode8 beta before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

up date your os to 10.11.6 it will work

Comment: @vasm Thanks...i !! But i have installed beta successfully on this.

Comment: yes beta is installed for me but xcode 8 not installing until we update  10.11.6 bro

Comment: On [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) wrote: Xcode 8 requires a Mac running macOS Sierra 10.12 or OS X El Capitan 10.11.5 or later.

Comment: but , am running Mac os El capitan but, still am unable to install xcode . i have tried xcode 9 and 8.3.3 and still getting this same old error.Is there any other way?